# SwiftUI NavigationView Starting Inside Itself

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

So I've got a NavigationView embedded inside of a TabView that is in the Page View Style. Upon first load the NavigationView will start inside itself, and then once reloaded it shows normally. I am unsure as to what is causing this. And I've made a GIF to better illustrate the problem:

[image]

**And here is my code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            SettingsView()
            EmptyView()
            EmptyView()
            EmptyView()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "1")) {
                        Text("1")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "2")) {
                        Text("2")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "3")) {
                        Text("3")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "4")) {
                        Text("4")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsItem: View {
    
    @State var title = "Title"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
    }
}

struct EmptyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.green
            Text("Empty View")
                .padding()
        }
        .border(Color.black, width: 8)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question.

Comment: I think that I've managed to make it clearer. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Have you found a solution to the wrong positioning of the list under the Navigation Title? Have the same issue ...

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution, in the end I had to completely redo it using HStacks and offsets, and based my solution off [this](https://medium.com/@xtabbas/implementing-snap-carousel-in-swiftui-3ae084504670) code.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, this has nothing to do with the `TabView()`. This is actually an issue in the SettingsView(). SwiftUI is defaulting to a split view. As a result, you are getting an empty view because you haven't actually navigated to any particular view, with the `Settings` back button showing. The fix to make this behave as you would expect is to add a `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()` on the `NavigationView` in `SettingsView` which forces `SettingsView` to display as a single view like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            SettingsView()
            BlankView(color: .green)
            BlankView(color: .blue)
            BlankView(color: .red)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "1")) {
                        Text("1")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "2")) {
                        Text("2")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "3")) {
                        Text("3")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "4")) {
                        Text("4")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct SettingsItem: View {
    
    @State var title = "Title"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
    }
}

struct BlankView: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            color
            Text("Blank View")
                .padding()
        }
        .border(Color.black, width: 8)
        
    }
}
```

Also, I edited your code a bit for clarity. `EmptyView()` is already designated by the system, so I changed it to `BlankView()` I am not sure why the compiler doesn't have a problem with you naming a struct EmptyView(), but you really shouldn't use that name. I also had the `BlankView()` show different colors so it was clear you were navigating to separate views.

Comment: For the most part this works perfectly, but upon first load the title appears to be lower than what it should be. Might be a strange bug. https://imgur.com/a/nZxmLz9

Comment: That isn’t an issue with a StackNavigationViewStyle. I use it just this way in production apps and don’t have an issue. It could be an anomaly in your minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I've just put your code into my app, and the anomaly still persists. Is there any way to remove it? Or to know what is causing the issue?

Comment: I haven’t hit that as an issue. Post that as a new question after researching that. It is frowned upon to try to solve another issue in comments. It makes it difficult for the next person to find an answer.