# SwiftUI NavigationView Title Starting Lower

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-tabview

So I've got a NavigationView embedded inside of a TabView that is in the Page View Style. Upon the first load, the NavigationView will start with its title lower than where it should be. Once I reload the view, by going to a different tab, it resets its self correctly. Is there a way that I can fix this issue so that it starts in the correct position? I've made a GIF to better illustrate the problem:

[image: My GIF]

And here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            SettingsView()
            BlankView(color: .green)
            BlankView(color: .blue)
            BlankView(color: .red)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("General")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "1")) {
                        Text("1")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "2")) {
                        Text("2")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "3")) {
                        Text("3")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: SettingsItem(title: "4")) {
                        Text("4")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct SettingsItem: View {
    
    @State var title = "Title"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(title)
    }
}

struct BlankView: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            color
            Text("Blank View")
                .padding()
        }
        .border(Color.black, width: 8)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` under `List` instead of `NavigationView`?

Comment: the problem seems to be `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))` if you comment it or use `.tabViewStyle(.automatic)` it works without the issue, well at least for me.

Comment: It looks like you have the same problem with Apple's Mail.

Comment: "... same problem with Apple's Mail" ???

P.S. you probably don't need another `NavigationView` in `SettingsItem`.

Comment: So, @thecoolwinter this "works" but creates the same problem as seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68844307/swiftui-navigationview-starting-inside-itself.

Comment: @workingdog, this does not work as I get the error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'automatic.' And thank you, you are correct I do not need another NavigationView in SettingsItem.

Comment: so if you remove `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))` it does not work for you? `.automatic` is for newer ios. What system are you on?

Comment: If I remove it and replace it with the .automatic the error that I mentioned above comes up. And I'm still on iOS 14. :/ I'd also like my app to be compatible with previous iOS versions too.

Comment: my question was if you remove `.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))` does it work for you?

Comment: just let us know if it works or not, then I'm done here. I don't do chat, sorry.

Comment: Sorry. I had no idea what I was getting into, StackOverflow just prompted it at me. If I remove it, it solves the problem. BUT it also eliminates the style that the modifier provided, making the solution not ideal.

Comment: @MrDuck Looks like a SwiftUI bug; `PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode:)` messing with tabs having a `NavigationView`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can report a SwiftUI bug?